# PHP validate input to find if user type in number followed by specific text

Tags: php

I have an input that a user can enter a number followed by (no spaces between): mi for minutes, hr for hours, dy for days, wk for weeks, or mo for months. So for example the user can enter 1mo. I want to check that the user entered a number followed by mi, hr, dy, wk, or mo with no spaces. the text needs to be written exactly like the above.

Here is what I got so far, but I am stuck:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Remember Me Length</label>
    <input type='text' class="form-control" name="settings[<?php echo $settings['remember_me_length']['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $remember_me_length; ?>" />
    <span id="helpBlock" class="help-block">You may enter any number, followed by (no spaces between): mi for minutes, hr for hours, dy for days, wk for weeks, or mo for months.</span> 
</div>


$cfgId = array();
$newSettings = $_POST['settings'];
//Validate remember me length
if ($newSettings[9] != $remember_me_length) {
    $newRemember_me_length = $newSettings[9];
    if(!in_array($newRemember_me_length, array('mi','hr','dy','wk','mo'), true )) {
        $errors[] = lang("CONFIG_INVALID_SPACE_LENGTH");
    } elseif (count($errors) == 0) {
        $cfgId[] = 9;
        $cfgValue[9] = $newRemember_me_length;
        $remember_me_length = $newRemember_me_length;
    }
}
```

Can someone please guide me in the right direction? If I need to include more info let me know.

Comment: Is this eventually going to be some sort of form submitted somewhere?

Comment: @jared yes, sorry i should've specified that in my question. the user will fill out the input and submit a form. Mike i have never worked with regular expressions and don't even know where to begin.

Comment: I would make number a field and then a radio maybe for the mi, hr, dy etc... Will be easier to use later if you need them separated.

Comment: I agree with AbraCadaver.  It's sometimes difficult to get the user to input the way you want.  Get your info from two separate controls, and concat later to avoid any issues, or leave as two pieces of data for further use.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for regular expressions:

```
if (preg_match('/\d+(mi|hr|dy|wk|mo)/', $value)) {
    echo 'valid';
} else {
    echo 'invalid';
}
```

Comment: could I use it like this: `!preg_match`?

Comment: However you should probably take abracadaver's advice and just get the user to input a number and have the time unit be a select box or radio.

Comment: I am using a module written by someone else and was trying to avoid that because even if I did that i still need to make sure the value submit is a digit with specific text and no spaces

Comment: If you did that, the digit and the time unit would be separate values in the `$_POST` array. You still need to detect errors (e.g. if someone tries to hack your site by including invalid values), but it is much more user-friendly to not allow the user to choose an invalid value.